Using INNER JOIN in SQLite only, join 2 tables from subqueries and select add some columns
I am stuck on how to select results from merging 2 tables together.
Overview:
I have 2 queries that return to me 2 tables as follows



Id1
name
score_total
count_score




1
Peter
50
2


2
John
25
3


3
David
100
6






id2
name
score_total
count_score




2
John
30
1


3
David
50
2


4
Cassidy
120
4



I want to create a table that looks like the first three columns shown below



id
name
average_score
explanation




1
Peter
25
50 / 2


2
John
13.75
(25 + 30) / (3 + 1)


3
David
18.75
(100 + 50) / (6 + 2)


4
Cassidy
30
120 / 4



How should I go about this using INNER JOIN only? (course forces me to use only inner join, but other suggestion are welcome)
SELECT cast_member_id, cast_name, collab_score / collab_count
FROM (
    SELECT
      cast_member_id1 AS cast_member_id,
      cast_name,
      printf('%.2f', SUM(average_movie_score)) as collab_score,
      COUNT(cast_member_id1) AS collab_count
    FROM good_collaboration
    JOIN movie_cast ON cast_member_id1 = movie_cast.cast_id
    GROUP BY cast_member_id1
) t1 INNER JOIN

(
    SELECT
      cast_member_id2 AS cast_member_id,
      cast_name,
      printf('%.2f', SUM(average_movie_score)) as collab_score,
      COUNT(cast_member_id1) AS collab_count
    FROM good_collaboration
    JOIN movie_cast ON cast_member_id2 = movie_cast.cast_id
    GROUP BY cast_member_id2
)t2

Here is a sample SQLite query I wrote.
I believe those 2 subqueries are already okay when I print them out and check, but I have a problem combining them

can you try the two solutions i added below ? let me know if they work if they do please consider upvote and accepting the answer

@Trillion please don't ask for upvotes. And please don't ask specifically for your answer to be awarded. Instead suggest that OP views all the answers provided and accepts the one that suits them best.

You want to treat two query results, as if they were one table. You achieve this with UNION ALL. (An inner join of the query results does not help you in this situation, because a member can be in the first table or the second or both. If you wanted to join them, you'd need a FULL OUTER JOIN.)
WITH 
  result1 AS
  (
    SELECT 
      gc.cast_member_id1 AS cast_member_id, 
      cast_name, 
      average_movie_score
    FROM good_collaboration gc
    JOIN movie_cast mc ON mc.cast_id = gc.cast_member_id1
  ),
  result2 AS
  (
    SELECT 
      gc.cast_member_id2 AS cast_member_id,
      cast_name, 
      average_movie_score
    FROM good_collaboration gc
    JOIN movie_cast mc ON mc.cast_id = gc.cast_member_id2
  ),
  one_table AS
  (
    SELECT cast_member_id, cast_name, average_movie_score FROM result1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cast_member_id, cast_name, average_movie_score FROM result2
  )
SELECT cast_member_id, cast_name, AVG(average_movie_score) AS average_score
FROM one_table
GROUP BY cast_member_id, cast_name
ORDER BY cast_member_id, cast_name;

As you have not qualified the columns cast_name and average_movie_score with their respective table names, we don't know which of the two tables they reside in. For this reason, I don't know whether this can be optimized. Maybe it's possible to invoke UNION ALL on only one of the tables and then join this unioned table to the other one.

As you mentioned if we can do it without using Inner Join, then you can use this solution:
Solution 1:
Join the table 1 and table 2 using full outer Join allowing us to have data from both tables into 1 table and then use COALESCE to fetch the first not null value after the join to be used in the avg calculation.
with main as (
  select 
   coalesce(t1.id1,t2.id2) as id,
   coalesce(t1.name,t2.name) as name,
   coalesce(t1.score_total, t2.score_total) as score_total,
   coalesce(t2.score_total,0) as score_total_2,
   coalesce(t1.count_score,t2.count_score) as count_score,
   coalesce(t2.count_score,0) as count_score_2
  from table1 as t1
  full outer join table2 as t2 
  on t1.id1 = t2.id2
  )
  
select id, name, 
  (score_total + score_total_2) / (count_score + count_score_2) as average_score
  from main


Solution Results: https://dbfiddle.uk/hQMHv7Dx
Solution 2:
Combine the results of your table 1 and table 2 together and simply calculate the average

with main as (

select id1 as id, name, score_total, count_score from table1
union all
select id2 as id, name, score_total, count_score from table2
)
  
select
  id,
  name,
  sum(score_total) / sum(count_score) as average_score
from main
group by id, name 


Solution 2 Results: https://dbfiddle.uk/4rg_XHKY
